# How to avoid that an executable cares about the dependencies of its dependencies?

Tags: c++, linux, dependencies, shared-libraries

Let be an executable *C.exe* depending on *libB.so* that itself depends on *libA.so*. *C.exe* doesn't use *libA* directly. The tool ldd shows that C.exe still need libA.so :

```
> ldd C.exe 
    libB.so => ./libB.so (0x00002b11cc4f5000)
    libA.so.1 => ./libA.so.1 (0x00002b11cc719000)
    <snip>
```

I would have thought that libA.so would show up only when inspecting libB.so. Is there a way to avoid that behavior or do you consider it correct ?

My problem is that libA can be updated to version 2 and thus the library name would change to libA.so.2. I recompiled libB but not C.exe. I was expecting C.exe to run fine because it depends on libB which knows which libA to choose, but it is not the case.

How to handle that case ?

### Compilation and Linking details

libA.so is compiled and linked this way:

```
g++ -fPIC -Wall -shared -Wl,-soname,libA.so.1 libA.cpp -o libA.so.1
ln -s libA.so.1 libA.so
```

libB.so is compiled and linked this way:

```
g++ -fPIC -Wall -shared -L. -lA libB.cpp -o libB.so
```

C.exe is compiled and linked this way:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
g++ -fPIC -Wall -L. -lB exeC.cpp -o C.exe
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to create libA as a static library (using `ar`). That way its code will be embedded into libB.so and you won't have the additional dependencies.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am a bit reluctant to use static library because libA is actually a huge set of libraries (root.cern.ch) that amount for several hundreds of MB.

Comment: Linking is "intelligent". It won't include the complete static library (depending on the compiler). So even if your static library is 100 MB, it's possible to only link 50 KB of it.